# Google Map Loading slow loading

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem with google map Loading and making center in my java script code it's working fine if we refreshed page or slick on fire bug.
Please help me as soon as possible 
code is in map view of  link 
http://www.myl.elocaldevelopment.com/ca/los-angeles/chiropractor/

Comment: Any of these duplicate questions would appear to hold the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+map+grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait to init the map until it's canvas is a visible element on the page. If you create the map on a hidden element then you need to call google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize') when it becomes visible.